# Can't see 1 TB drive after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I wiped Win 10 off a new computer and installed Ubuntu 20.04 via USB drive on a new computer. The computer has 2 drives, a 250 GB one (which I installed Ubuntu on) and a 1000 GB one.

In system monitor, I can only see one of my hard drives, which is the one I installed Ubuntu on [1].

I thought that Ubuntu would automatically know to store information on my 1 TB drive seamlessly, but it seems I may have to change something?

In BIOS drive settings, my computer is set to AHCI, not ATA, and all SATA (-0, -1, and -2) drives are highlighted.

There was a bit of an issue during the install - I had to change the BIOS boot order from "Legacy" (and unchecked all boxes there) to "UEFI" which had Ubuntu in it - maybe I need to check an option in Legacy?

Aside from these thoughts I don't know how to connect my 1 TB drive to Ubuntu, so I would greatly appreciate any help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLNvx.jpg

Comment: Do you see it in the "Disks" application?  How many partitions and what file system(s) are being used on the 1TB drive?

Comment: Hi Nmath, yes I can see it in "disks". It says Partition 1, with 1 TB "NFTS". My 256 GB disk is Partition 2, thank you for your help

Comment: If you are ok with erasing the drive, you can format the 1TB drive using the Disks application.  If you aren't using Windows then you probably shouldn't use NTFS which is a Microsoft proprietary file system for Windows.  Ubuntu can read and write to NTFS but if your system is Ubuntu only, then ext4 is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks Nmath, would you suggest I install gparted to format the 1TB drive to ext4 from NTFS? And this is referred to as an automount?

Comment: I personally find "Disks" to be more user friendly.  I will post an answer with instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with erasing the disk you can format the 1TB disk so that it is compatible with Ubuntu.

- Open the **Disks** application (`gnome-disk-utility`)
- In the left column, choose the disk you would like to format.
- In the top right corner of the application, choose the options menu and select **Format Disk...**
- Since this will be a data partition, you can choose a "**Quick**" erase and use "**MBR / DOS**" partitioning.
- Click **Format...**
- Accept the confirmation after you have verified that the format operation is going to applied to the correct disk.
- After the disk is formatted, again make sure it is selected in the left column.  Then select the disk in the right side of the application.  It should say "**Free Space**".
- With "**Free Space**" selected, click the `+` button underneath the selected volume.
- Unless you want multiple partitions, accept the maximum partition size, and click "**Next**".
- Give the volume a "**Volume Name**".  Select "**Internal disk for use with Linux systems only (Ext4)**".  Then click "**Create**".

Creating the file system may take a few moments.  Once the file system is created, the disk should automatically mount itself and it should also automatically mount during boot.

Comment: Thanks NMath, I did actually format it to ext4 in gparted then saw your answer, which has allowed me to also mount the drive in the Disks application

Comment: While you can use the old MBR(msdos) partitioning, there are some advantages to gpt. The only time MBR is now required is for installing Windows in BIOS boot mode. Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI install. And BIOS Windows installs read gpt drives. GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT